# Cannot update grub with parameters on live USB

Tags: grub2, 12.10, live-usb

I have booted from a live USB ("Try Ubuntu"), that also has a persistent option set (I used [LiLi](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) to create one) to do some tests for [this pcie hotplug issue I'm having](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153813/crippling-repeating-pciehp-card-not-present-notifications).

I'm trying to test [some boot paramaters](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ExpressCard) (like [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-boot-parameter)) by doing this

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

The problem is that that last command gives me this:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of /cow.
```

It looks like `/cow` is the file-system that is mounted on `/`, according to:

```
:~# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/cow             4056896 2840204   1007284  74% /
udev             1525912       4   1525908   1% /dev
tmpfs             613768     844    612924   1% /run
....
```

Is there a way for me to run update-grub?

Comment: Having this same problem when running update-grub as original poster. When trying to mount /cow, gives error "mount: special device /cow does not exist" Any ideas?

Comment: This one worked for me: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: Running grub-mkconfig with the proposed command from here showed the error for me. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=736928

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You'll need to do a bit of remounting and remapping.

After booting the liveCD, we'll mount the Ubuntu partition to `/mnt` with:

```
sudo mount /dev/sd*# /mnt
```

where `/dev/sd*#` is updated to your Ubuntu partition.

If you have a separate `/boot` partition, we'll need to mount it in `/mnt/boot` as well:

```
sudo mount /dev/sd*# /mnt/boot
```

where `/dev/sd*#` is updated to your `/boot` partition.

This should mount it with enough access to get the canonical path if needed, but we'll likely not need this.

To finish up, just update grub with the correct root and target:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdX
```

where `/dev/sdX` is the disk(not the partition) where we want GRUB.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. What do you mean by "the Ubuntu partition" ? I'm not trying to change the boot parameters of the persistent USB drive, not of some other install?

Comment: @Nanne The partition mounted at `/` of the installation in which you wish to configure GRUB.

Comment: I am booting from a usb-key. I want to reboot with that same key, but then with different parameters. There is only 1 installation, the one on the usb key. So the partition mounted at / of the installation I want to configure is 'currently' mounted at /

Comment: Yes, as long as this is a full installation on said key.

Comment: hmm, sounds good, recursive mounting :) .. I'll give it a shot ;)

Comment: Tried this, and got "Attempting to install GRUB to a partition disk or to a partition.  This is a BAD idea.
Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists. 
However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged.". Tried --force which made it install, but it destroyed grub and left the USB stick unbootable. That was with 14.04. Any other ideas?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the sd*# is a software RAID array.

Comment: When I run the last command, I get [`error: will not proceed with blocklists.`](https://gist.github.com/fe6c7e87c47aa5477c06).

Comment: @zenith that's because your disk is partitioned using GPT. I don't have a system with it so I'm not particularly familiar with its operation and how a bootloader works on it.

Comment: You save my life man! **where `/dev/sdX` is the disk(not the partition)**!!!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just needed to install grub.

```
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install grub
```