# Fresh Ubuntu installation won't get past GRUB. Stuck in loop

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2

I have a fresh Ubuntu 14.04.1 installation. I installed it from a Live USB. I installed it by itself, so any existing OS was erased.

The installation went flawlessly.  When I rebooted after the installation, I'm greeted with the Grub screen.  Selecting Ubuntu on this list reboots the computer, where I'm greeted again with the Grub screen.  There doesn't seem to by any way past the Grub screen.

I followed these instructions: https://askubuntu.com/a/527329/451700   but that made things even worse.  When I reboot the computer, it appears that my entire OS was overwritten by the Grub.

I've tried reinstalling again from scratch, but still get stuck in that Grub loop

Comment: What is you video adapter?

Answer (score 0):

From your description I guess the following scenario:

Grub cannot find the correct partition or drive. The whole rest of your system is installed normally.

Since you have the Grub screen, you can probably boot your system from the Grub commandline. First you have to find your root partition.

```
find /vmlinuz
```

this will hopefully give you the root partition, something like (hd0,0). There is also the `ls` and `search` commands which work similar to the normal linux shell commands. *Tab completion* also works. Next, you set the root partition (use the values that the previous find command gives you)

```
set root=(hd1,1)
```

then set the linux kernel:

```
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1
```

next set the initial ramdisk image

```
initrd /initrd.img
```

then boot

```
boot
```

There is [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21342/how-can-i-load-ubuntu-when-all-i-have-is-grub) which describes the same procedure. There are [also](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-grub-commands.html) [other](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/) [pages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromUSB) that my contain useful information.

A thorough description of Grub2 is found on [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2).