# Not booting into Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu and Windows 8. The grub boot loader fails to load Ubuntu.

It was automatically loading Ubuntu in few seconds but not anymore.

So, I manually choose Ubuntu but it shows some scripts and fails to boot.

Even Windows 8 doesn't boot.

It's now showing something like this:
error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'. Entering rescue mode..grub rescue>
I tried this -
grub rescue > ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos6)(hd0, msdos5) (hd0, msdos4) (hd0, msdos3) (hd0, msdos2) (hd0, msdos1)
I then tried this-
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdosX)
but it doesn't show which is my Linux file!!
grub rescue> failed to read file.
Please help me I have so many data in my pc  :(

Comment: Please give us more information, like what error message do you get etc.

Comment: It doesn't start from grub. The grub seems fine but Ubuntu is not loading!!

Comment: The scripts are like ata4:hard resting link, unhandled error, usb 5-1: Usb disconnect, new low speed device found etc.

Comment: Please check the answer here on how to update grub:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/207663/cannot-update-grub-with-paramters-on-live-usb

Comment: Not its not working now it's showing grub error

Comment: Now my computer shows no boot devices available

Comment: It's now showing something like this error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'. Entering rescue mode..grub rescue>>

Comment: You should try data recovery before trying to repair the OS. Especially if your hard drive is failing. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry friends it's my fault, the problem was with the hdd and it wasn't detected in my bios but its really working now after I reinstalled in motherboard. I doubted so when I tried to install Ubuntu from live disk then it showed I don't have enough space. I was confirmed after checking it out in bios. Feeling relaxed. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Ubuntu DVD. Choose "Try Ubuntu" option when it does provide two options of "Try Ubuntu" and "Install Ubuntu". Then, open up the Terminal, type `sudo update-grub`. Upon executing the command, reboot the system and check out if it does boot. If the issue persists, comment the error message.

Comment: How to open terminal? Should I choose try Ubuntu then alt-cntl-t?

Comment: I choosed try Ubuntu and typed as you said in terminal but shows failed to get canonical parh

Comment: You could Ctrl+Alt+T to open Terminal. Then, you could type `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: No it doesn't work

Comment: Check out this link. http://www.howopensource.com/2012/05/reinstall-recover-grub-from-ubuntu-12-04-live-cd-usb/.