# Problems after Installation

Tags: 17.04

So I tried dual booting my desktop today which has windows 7 installed on hard disk one which only contains the windows partition. I tried to install Ubuntu 17.04 on hard disk 2, which is on a 1 tb partition (sdb4). I tried boot repair and it does not seem to have done anything of use. Now when I try to load disk 1 it gives me a error with grub rescue and when I try and load disk2 it goes in a loop where it just keeps rebooting until I stop it. I have no clue where to begin to fix this. Any help at all fixing this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
Disk 2: Partition 1: 135 mb (Microsoft reserved)
Partition 2: 3TB (Basic data partition)
Partition 3: 1 mb (Bios Boot)
Partition 4: 1 TB (Linux Filesystem)

Answer (score 2):

You can fix your grub using your live CD.

1. Boot with your Ubuntu live CD again and enter a live session.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open the Terminal.
3. Type `sudo update-grub` and wait.
4. Reboot to see if your grub got fixed. If not, try typing `sudo grub-install` to reinstall the grub.

**Edit:**

Since you can't update your grub using `update-grub`, I am giving you a solution (refer to [Cannot update grub with parameters on live USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207663/cannot-update-grub-with-parameters-on-live-usb)):

After booting the live CD, Mount your Ubuntu partition to `/mnt` with:

```
sudo mount /dev/sd*# /mnt
```

where `/dev/sd*#` is updated to your Ubuntu partition.

If you have a separate `/boot` partition, mount it in `/mnt/boot` as well:

```
sudo mount /dev/sd*# /mnt/boot
```

where `/dev/sd*#` is updated to your `/boot` partition.

Update grub with the correct root and target:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdX
```

where `/dev/sdX` is the disk(not the partition) where grub is installed.

Comment: Which drive should I be booting from?

Comment: Just boot your live CD first. You can fix your boot menu from your live CD.

Comment: Just tried that and it is giving me the error : "/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failled to get canonical path of 'aufs'.".

Comment: Refer to [https://askubuntu.com/questions/207663/cannot-update-grub-with-parameters-on-live-usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207663/cannot-update-grub-with-parameters-on-live-usb). See if that helps.

Comment: Just did that. It's still caught in a loop.

Comment: Edit your post and specify all your hardware properties. I'll see what went wrong.

Comment: I think I added my hardware ties. If I am missing something please let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59151/discussion-between-cynplytholowazy-and-andrew).