# apt-upgrade kernel-image with custom kernel

Tags: 12.10, apt, kernel, updates

I'm running a kernel I compiled myself (because of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153813/crippling-repeating-pciehp-card-not-present-notifications)) and I'm wondering what apt will do with kernel updates?

The software updater currently lists (among others) these points:

- Conmplete Generic Linux kernel and headers
  *(linux-generic)*
- Header files related to linux kernel version 3.5.0
- (linux-headers-3.5.0-19) *
- Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
  *(linux-image-3.5.0-19-generic (New install)*
- Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
  *(linux-image-extra-3.5.0-19-generic (New install)*
- Generic Linux kernel image
  *(linux-image-generic)*
- Linux Kernel Headers for development
  *(linux-libc-dev)*

That last one isn't really a problem I presume, but included for completeness.

**To know what's going on:**
Will `apt` try to replace my kernel with a newer one, does it update the default kernel (I never got rid of any packages for the standard kernel) and ignores the one in use, or something else entirely?

**ToDo**:
Should I ignore (deselect) them during updates(tricky, that'll be forgotten once), just update them, or should I uninstall some of these packages?

Comment: I think I listed all related packages, could be I forgot to inlcude one about kernel-headers, proving the point that deselecting them if I shouldn't update them isn't too fault-tolerant in the longer run :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing kernel updates will not influence the custom one.

However, the update will update grub. When I installed a mainline kernel, since it had a higher number it was made as the default kernel.

So if your kernel has a higher number you shouldn't worry.

If your kernel is lower than 3.5.0-19, the update will make the newly installed kernel default. You can set the kernel you want as default by changing the `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` line to `GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2"` in /etc/default/grub. 1, means the second option in the first page of the Grub menu and the 2 means the third one on the second page (Counting starts from 0).

Comment: Should I remove some of these packages? No sense in updating a kernel that won't work anyway? Just extra time in downloads and all...

Comment: I usually uninstall old kernels, leaving just one backup just in case.

Comment: so an `apt-get remove linux-image-3.5.0-19-generic ` is feasible? (if I'm sure that indeed I use a different kernel :)  )

Comment: Yes. You may remove the headers package as well.