# How to prevent kernel or any broadcast messages from flooding the TTYs?

Tags: command-line, kernel, display, tty, hotplug

Is there a way to stop the ttys from being flooded by the kernel messages? The display shows a continuous stream of messages (which are also logged in the /var/log directory). Every text I key in flows away visually, but it does take the inputs. I can log in and run commands.

Comment: This is not standard behaviour: Unless you run a program like `gedit` from a terminal...  What messages are you talking about?  (screenshot of an untouched terminal not running any applications?)

Comment: it's hot-plugging issue messages.. similar to what talked of [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/153813/crippling-repeating-pciehp-card-not-present-notifications).. I don't want to be trying the recompile solution right away, so just looking to manage the error messages (temporarily)..